# ASP.Net MVC -- "Google’s MarkerManager"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, razor

Been chasing a rabbit, and time to ask for help before I get any further down this rabbit hole. I have been trying to implement a Google Map with multiple markers. I was trying to use the code I found on ChangSu’s Tech blog at https://csjlsolutions.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/how-to-put-multiple-markers-in-google-map-in-mvc-4/. I managed to get my google map to display, but none of the markers displayed. By using the browsers' development tool, I saw that the java script could not find Google’s MarkerManager. After looking around some more, I used the Package Manager Console to install Jmelosegui.Mvc.Googlemap (version 0.8.0.0) (see http://www.jmelosegui.com/map/).

After installing this package, I started getting a new error:

Conflicting versions of ASP.NET Web Pages detected: specified version is “1.0.0.0”, but version in bin is “3.0.0.0”. To continues remove files from application’s bin directory or remove the version specification in web.config

More looking around, and updated my web.config to version 3 (it was version 1.0.0.0)

<appSettings>

```
add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" /
```

Now I have syntax error.

@foreach (var place in Model) {

```
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng("@place.MonumentLocationLat", "@place.MonumentLocationLong");
```

Not sure which way to turn on this. Should I start from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I think when I installed Jmelosegui.Mvc.Googlemap it really messed up something somewhere. I was getting errors about version mismatches and all kinds of strange things. I have fallen back to a previous version of my code (aren't backups nice) and have managed to get my map to displays. I

My Solution

**Controller**

```
        // -------------------- Display a Map of the Battlefield showing the location of all of the monuments that have been entered to the DB  -------------------------------------------------
    public ActionResult MapMonuments(string battleRecID)
    {

        var monumentMap = from s in db.Monuments
                          where ((s.MonumentBattleRecID == battleRecID) &&

                            (s.MonumentStatus == "A"))

                          select s;


        ViewBag.avgLat = monumentMap.Average(s => s.MonumentLocationLat);
        ViewBag.avgLong = monumentMap.Average(s => s.MonumentLocationLong);


        return PartialView(monumentMap.ToList());
    }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<CWBFM.Models.Monument>
```

```
  // avgLat  = the average of all of the latitudes
  // avgLong = the average of all of the longitudes

    Int_Map("@ViewBag.avgLat", "@ViewBag.avgLong");
```

// Where all the fun happens

```
function Int_Map(avgLat, avgLong) {


    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(avgLat, avgLong);

    // These are options that set initial zoom level, where the map is centered globally to start, and the type of map to show
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        }

    }

    // This makes the div with id "map_canvas" a google map

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    // place a marker on the map for each monument

    @foreach (var place in Model) {

    <text>
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng("@place.MonumentLocationLat", "@place.MonumentLocationLong");
    var markerTitle = "@place.MonumentName"; // input the monuments name from the database
    var URL = "http://cwbfm.org/Monument/MonumentDetails/" + "@place.MonumentID"; // create the url to link to the monuments detail page

    // set the marker icon based on the Allegiance
    switch ("@place.MonumentAllegiance") {
        case "B":
            var image = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-circle.png';
            break;
        case "C":
            var image = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle.png';
            break;
        case "U":
            var image = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/blu-circle.png';
            break;
        default:
            var image = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/ylw-circle.png';
    }

    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        icon: image,
        title: markerTitle,
        url: URL,
        map: map
    });

        // on click, go to the monuments detail page
        google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, "click", function () {
          window.location.href = this.url;
      });


    </text>


} return
```

}

This works fine for me.